Unable to send emails from local server with Cpanel
I am not able to send emails for all Cpanel accounts. It fails trying to send the emails and then they has the message of "max defers and failures per hour (5/5 100%) allowed.". Can any one help me to solve it?
My tests
[root@serv ~]# netstat -tuplen | grep 25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         30232      2240/pdns_server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          22232      870/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         27984      2240/pdns_server
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          17825      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          22231      870/exim
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      25         27985      2240/pdns_server
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           25         27982      2240/pdns_server
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                25         27983      2240/pdns_server

and check outgoing port 25, but not success.
[root@serv ~]# curl portquiz.net:25
curl: (28) Failed to connect to portquiz.net port 25: Connection timed out

And firewall is not blocking it
[root@serv ~]# iptables -L -n | grep :25
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
ACCEPT     6    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:25
ACCEPT     6    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:25
ACCEPT     17   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:25

So I don't know what to do. ConfigServer Security & Firewall has added port 25 on TCP and UPD out as well.
Other thing I don't know why I have this
[root@server etc]# host server.miexampledomain.com
Host server.miexampledomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)


You need to check with your provider or datacenter if they are block port 25 from their side
